added bot_token by mistake when creating client on pyrogram
I'm creating my first project on pyrogram and, by mistake, after the usual...
api_id = api_id

api_hash = "hash_id"

async def main():

async with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app:

    await app.send_message("me", "Greetings from **Pyrogram**!")

asyncio.run(main())

I by mistake added the bot token instead of my phone number when asked. Now I don't know how to restart the process and insert my phone number.
I tried restarting the program, but it led me to
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.UserIsBot
and now I can't restart the process.

To resolve this issue and restart the login process with your phone number instead of a bot token:
1. Delete the session file
Locate and delete the file named my_account.session in your project directory. This file was created when you ran the script using the bot token.
2. Restart the script
After deleting the session file, rerun your script. You will be prompted again to choose between logging in with:
A phone number, or
A bot token.
3. Select your phone number
This time, input your phone number when prompted.
